# String to binary and vice versa: extended ASCII

Tags: java, string, binary, byte

I want to convert a String to binary by putting it in a byte array (`String.getBytes[]`) and then store the binary string for each byte (`Integer.toBinaryString(bytearray)`) in a String[]. Then I want to convert back to normal String via `Byte.parseByte(stringarray[i], 2)`. This works great for standard ASCII-Table, but not for the extended one. For example, an `A` gives me `1000001`, but an `Ä` returns

```
11111111111111111111111111000011
11111111111111111111111110000100
```

Any ideas how to manage this?

```
public class BinString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String s = "ä";
        System.out.println(binToString(stringToBin(s)));

    }

    public static String[] stringToBin(String s) {
        System.out.println("Converting: " + s);
        byte[] b = s.getBytes();
        String[] sa = new String[s.getBytes().length];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            sa[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(b[i] & 0xFF);
        }
        return sa;
    }

    public static String binToString(String[] strar) {
        byte[] bar = new byte[strar.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < strar.length; i++) {
            bar[i] = Byte.parseByte(strar[i], 2);
            System.out.println(Byte.parseByte(strar[i], 2));

        }
        String s = new String(bar);
        return s;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off: "extended ASCII" is a very misleading title that's used to refer to a ton of different encodings.

Second: `byte` in Java is signed, while bytes in encodings are usually handled as unsigned. Since you use `Integer.toBinaryString()` the `byte` will be converted to an `int` using sign extension (because byte values > 127 will be represented by negative values in Java).

To avoid this simply use `& 0xFF` to mask all but the lower 8 bit like this:

```
String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(byteArray[i] & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't get it work. I thoought Java don't work with unsigned bytes? How can I convert an unsigned byte back to a char?

Comment: I see, I have to use `bar[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(strar[i], 2);`for backconversion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

*To expand on [Joachim's point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535988/string-to-binary-and-vice-versa-extended-ascii/5536013#5536013) about "extended ASCII" I'd add...*

Note that [`getBytes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) is a transcoding operation that converts data from UTF-16 to the platform default encoding. The encoding varies from system to system and sometimes even between users on the same PC. This means that results are not consistent on all platforms and if a legacy encoding is the default (as it is on Windows) that data can be lost.

To make the operation symmetrical, you need to [provide an encoding explicitly](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.nio.charset.Charset%29) (preferably a Unicode encoding such as UTF-8 or UTF-16.)

```
Charset encoding = Charset.forName("UTF-16");
byte[] b = s1.getBytes(encoding);
String s2 = new String(b, encoding);
assert s1.equals(s2);
```