# how to handle ascii non-printable characters in java

Tags: java, ascii

We have people sending non-printable \x86 type of characters in byte array in Java and when we convert it to us-ascii string, it inserts junk character in the ascii text.

Is there a format for string/other way to handle non-printable ascii characters while converting data from formats like EBCDIC to ASCII in Java?

Comment: Strings in Java are UTF-16. How are you doing your conversion from the byte array to the String? Are you simply doing: `new String(byteArray, "US-ASCII");` Perhaps this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5536013/355499

Comment: If they are really EBCDIC bytes, Java supports [three EBCDIC encodings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html): namely IBM500/Cp500, x-IBM834/Cp834 and IBM1047/Cp1047; you can use one of them to convert EBCDIC bytes to US-ASCII string as suggested by @EmilH. Unrelated solution, you can convert EBCDIC characters to Unicode equivalent as shown in http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-gremlins.htm

Answer (score 1):

How would you like to handle them? Replace them with something printable (such as '?')? Remove them entirely? Some other action?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the US or "Western Europe" (UK, France, Germany), the character set probably is [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). Single-byte charset US-ASCII covers 128 characters, single-byte charset Windwos-1252 is a superset covering all 255 characters in the byte range.

Easiest is a translation table for \u0080 - \u00ff. String, as some might be better replaced by several chars, say \u008c by "OE".